# Web slash trouble in cross OS

Tags: php, linux, web-services, backslash, slash

Here is how I define my root folder:

```
<?php
    define('BASEDIR', dirname(__DIR__).'/');
?>
```

It should be no problem in Linux, or at least that what I think. However, I develop my website on Windows with Wamp, so a slash (/) has been turned into backslash (\). And that's my problem, check my test code:

```
<?php
    echo BASEDIR.'user.json'
    //result: C:\wamp\www\website/user.json
?>
```

What should I do? I can't not just replace all the slash for Linux to backslash for Window. Because in the end, I will upload it to a Linux host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant to avoid these situations. Example below:

```
require_once DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'libs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Boostrap.php'
```